# How to get double precision number from Point object

Tags: java, casting, point

I have a Point object and I want it to return a double to my variable `x`. How do I do it without casting it?

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Main {
    public Main()  {
      Point point = new Point(1, 1);
      Double doub = point.x; // Dosent work. Returns an int

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```

I get the error: "Cannot convert int from double"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the getter function in the point object. This will return a double

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Main {
    public Main()  {
      Point point = new Point(1, 1);
      Double doub = point.getX(); // Returns double, You dont have to cast

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();
    }
}
```